# Structuring group messages firebase

Tags: firebase, data-structures, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I am working on a message-board application that would allow administrators to send messages to a specific group of people. People can be subscribed to multiple groups.

I need a list for a user which shows all his messages for the groups that he is subscribed to. I made the following structure:

```
{
    "placeMessages": {
        "<place-push-key>": {
            "message-push-key": {
                "user_id": "<user-push-key>",
                "place_id": "<place-push-key>",
                "subject": ""
                "message": ""
                "date": "<date>"
            }
        }
    },
    "userMessages": {
        "<user-push-key>": {
            "message-push-key": {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem is that when an administrator sends a message, the message needs to be added to all the users that are subscribed to that group. This could mean a atomic write action of 10.000 messages. I expect that this would be very slow, is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following JSON give an idea about how to solve your problem.

```
{
    "groups": [{
        "groupId": "001",
        "messages": [{
            "messageId": "001_1001",
            "subject": ""
            "message": ""
            "date": "<date>"
        }, {
            "messageId": "001_1002",
            "subject": ""
            "message": ""
            "date": "<date>"
        }]
    }, {
        "groupId": "002",
        "messages": [{
            "messageId": "002_1001",
            "subject": ""
            "message": ""
            "date": "<date>"
        }, {
            "messageId": "002_1002",
            "subject": ""
            "message": ""
            "date": "<date>"
        }]
    }],

    "users": [{
        "userId": 10001,
        "subscribedGroups": ["001", "002"]
    }, {
        "userId": 100012,
        "subscribedGroups": ["001"]
    }, {
        "userId": 100013,
        "subscribedGroups": ["002"]
    }]
}
```

Note: This is not the actual solution for your problem. I'm solved the problem in a generalized way.

Comment: How would you write thr rules for this one so that the user can write and read the data in their subsribedgroup